Trouble Rendering 3D Game Env Built with Custom Godot
I am trying to render the following open-source game, built using a custom Godot binary:
https://github.com/Avalon-Benchmark/avalon

I would like to use it as a benchmark to run some Reinforcement Learning algorithms I am studying. currently, I am using V100 or A100 GPUs provided by Google Colab, but I have access to Oracle servers as well, which I can use to create virtual machines with the necessary computing power. However, I keep running into the same issue for so long now and I'm at a loss. I get some variation of the following error:

Godot Engine v3.4.4.stable.avalon.e462a8744 - https://godotengine.org
ERROR: Error initializing GLAD
at: is_viable (drivers/gles3/rasterizer_gles3.cpp:141)
Your video card driver does not support any of the supported OpenGL versions.
Please update your drivers or if you have a very old or integrated GPU, upgrade it.
Alternatively, you can force software rendering by running Godot with the LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 environment variable set, but this will be very slow.

I run into the same issues on the VMs on the Oracle servers.
Basically, I am trying to render a 3D game using a custom Godot binary, that shows as version 3.4.4. For all the GPUs that I have been trying to use, I can't seem to find one with a video card driver that supports the APIs used by Godot.
When I check the video card driver, here is what I get for the Colab GPUs:
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.104.05 Driver Version: 535.104.05 CUDA Version: 12.2 |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU Name Persistence-M | Bus-Id Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan Temp Perf Pwr:Usage/Cap | Memory-Usage | GPU-Util Compute M. |
| | | MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
| 0 Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB Off | 00000000:00:04.0 Off | 0 |
| N/A 34C P0 24W / 300W | 0MiB / 16384MiB | 0% Default |
| | | N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes: |
| GPU GI CI PID Type Process name GPU Memory |
| ID ID Usage |
|=======================================================================================|
| No running processes found |

Which are the latest stable versions as far I can tell. I also tried downgrading the driver to version 470 (I saw another user suggest this), but I don't think I can do so on Colab.
I haven't tried downgrading the drivers on these machines (or any other workaround with these machines) yet, as computing instances are expensive and I am budgeting how I much I use them, and I'd rather not waste time with solutions that may not work. But if anyone has familiarity with the servers and can guide me on how to custom-build a VM so that it supports all APIs utilized by Godot, I would be very appreciative of the guidance.
Then I checked the Godot engine that Avalon uses. The repo shows it as version 3.4.4 but the authors also said it is a custom build, which makes me think that may be a source of the problem. Though, I'm unsure.
